# ASP.NET email Regular Expression not working with hyphen just before the @

Tags: .net, regex, validation

I have the following ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:regularexpressionvalidator id="RegularExpressionValidator7"
            runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="Email1" 
            ErrorMessage="Email not valid" 
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
```

As you can see, the validation expression is the one that Visual Web Developer gives as default.  It has always worked great for me, until someone tried to enter this e-mail address:

johnsmith-@hotmail.com

The validator says that the email is not valid, but it is.  I verified at hotmail.com and you can create an e-mail address with a hyphen just before the @ symbol.

What must I change in the validation expression to accept this hyphen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an optional hyphen (`-?`) before the `@` in your regex.

```
ValidationExpresion="\w+([-+.]\w+)*-?@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
....................change.here....^^
```

Are you allowed a `+` just before the hyphen too? Then you'd add it in like

```
ValidationExpresion="\w+([-+.]\w+)*[-+]?@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
.....................change.here...^^^^^
```

and so on.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I did the change you told me and now it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

the plus quantifier in the first group becomes *

```
\w+([-+.]\w*)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

Comment: wait..  that will allow bladi.bladi.@something.com or bladi.bladi+@something.com that's not good :(

Comment: bladi.bladi+@something.com is a valid email address

Comment: @PHeiberg really? but what about bladi.bladi.@something.com?